# strange behaviour of $?

Tags: bash

I have a simple script:

```
greptest
------------
#!/bin/bash
. /opt/apps/algo/alcr5/TOP/shrc
$RTCE_HOME/bin/utils/serverlist.sh|grep Ugli|grep '\*\*' >/dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

the output of

```
$RTCE_HOME/bin/utils/serverlist.sh|grep Ugli
```

is:

```
Ugli  1         pid 28410 :    625060       00:46        86
```

so script greptest should print 1. but it prints 0.

Now if I command out:

```
source /opt/apps/algo/alcr5/TOP/shrc
```

the output is correct. /opt/apps/algo/alcr5/TOP/shrc is a script defines some variables and functions.

There is no error prompted when sourcing the shrc file. what can it be that affects $? value of next command?

Comment: The result (`$?` is 0) looks correct to me; I think that grep pattern isn't doing what you think it is. `grep '\*\*'` will match *any* line, because the regular expression `/*` will match zero or more slashes, and any line at all will contain two instances of zero or more slashes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: `/*` will match zero or more slashes, but `\*\*` will match two asterisks, because they are escaped.

Comment: I get a consistent result (as a child process or sourced) in `$?` of 1 if I echo the output given into `grep`.  But I'm running `bash`, not `/bin/shrc` (whatever that is).   Do you have anything set in startup files like `.bashrc` that could affect it?

Comment: I use /bin/bash. /opt/apps/algo/alcr5/TOP/shrc is a file contains some variable and function definition.  if I comment out the value of $? reflect the status of the last command.

Comment: 1 is the expected value of `$?` when the previous `grep` fails to find a match. It's not clear what you are expecting without seeing the contents of `shrc`.

Comment: @chepner: shrc is a script sourced to define variables and functions. it has nothing to do with the next command. since grep will not find a match in the next command output, it should print 1. but it actually printed 0. and if I don't source shrc. the output is correct (1). that is what I think as strange behavior...

Comment: @cdarke Oops, apparently I wasn't fully awake when I commented.

Comment: @AlexL You get different behavior when you source `shrc` than when you don't, but you don't think the contents of `shrc` are relevant?

Comment: Of course `$?` gives the result of the rightmost command in a pipeline.  It might be instructive to `echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` after the command in each case.  If you haven't seen it before, `PIPESTATUS` is an array of results from each part of the pipeline.

Answer (score -2):

Use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/shrc` if you use bash.

Comment: That was a typo. I use #!/bin/bash interpreter.